# Deleting from multiple tables mysql with php

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have literally tried everything i've found on the internet about deleting from multiple tables in same query, but it just ends up deleting from the first table(Posts)..

So how does one do this the correct way with php and pdo?

examples of what i've tried=

```
$dsn = "DELETE FROM Posts, Comments USING Posts, Comments WHERE Posts.ID = Comments.PostID  AND Comments.PostID=:my var";

$dsn = "DELETE FROM Posts LEFT JOIN Comments ON `Comments.PostID` = `Posts.ID` WHERE `Posts.ID`=:tit";

$dsn = "DELETE Posts , Comments  FROM Posts  INNER JOIN Comments  WHERE Posts.ID = Comments.PostID and Posts.ID =:myvar";
```

The tables looks as following:

```
 TABLE: Posts

    ID(PK AI) 
    Title(VARCHAR)
    Post(VARCHAR)
    Author(VARCHAR)
    Date(DATETIME)



TABLE: Comments

ID(PK AI so all comments get unique id's)
Name(VARCHAR)
Comment(VARCHAR)
Date(DATETIME
PostID(INT)
```

Comment: If you define `Coments.PostID` as FK with `ON DELETE CASCADE`, you will just need to delete from `Posts`.

Comment: @PaulSpiegel that sounds intressting, just need to find out how to do that then :)

Comment: Look at the first example here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html

Comment: post an MCVE. post your tables

Comment: @e4c5 sorry, im not sure what you mean

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @e4c5 better now? sorry for the sloppy post..

Comment: MCVE stands for Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example. http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.

Comment: can't really say there has been much of an improvement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have different ways to solve this:
1- **delete with inner join**

```
$dsn = "DELETE Posts.*, Comments.*  FROM Posts  INNER JOIN Comments  WHERE Posts.ID = Comments.PostID and Posts.ID =:myvar";
```

2- **delete cascade, drop if exist foreing key and execute this:**

```
ALTER TABLE Comments
  ADD CONSTRAINT fk_postid 
  FOREIGN KEY (PostID) 
  REFERENCES Posts(ID) 
  ON DELETE CASCADE;
```

3- **using trigger after delete in the table Posts**

```
  delimiter $$
    CREATE TRIGGER `after_delete_Posts`     
      AFTER DELETE ON `Posts`     
      FOR EACH ROW     
    BEGIN
      DELETE FROM Comments where PostID = OLD.id;
    END
    $$
    delimiter ;
```

Comment: I tried with the cascade, i dropped the FK and AI on ID in comments then ran your query and got this: #1452 - Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`pelle`.`#sql-c32d_67e16`, CONSTRAINT `fk_postid` FOREIGN KEY (`PostID`) REFERENCES `Posts` (`ID`) ON DELETE CASCADE) i have tried the delete query before, it doesnt work im afraid

Comment: The definition of the data type of both postID and ID are the same?

Comment: before alter table add this:`SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;` ,and after add `SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1;`